# Connecting Power BI desktop from Virtual Machine to Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp, powerbi

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 on my machine, so I have LAMP set up. I'm using Virtual Machine for Windows based apps. I've got Power BI Desktop running on my VM and would like to connect it to my local mysql DB.

It can't connect to it using neither `localhost`, nor my local `IP (192.168.1.123 in this case).`

Do I need to set up a port forwarding? Or is it just not possible to connect to my local DB like that?

Comment: How did you set your VM network configuration? Check if your VM have access to the network of your host.

Answer (score 0):

If your localhost is inside the VM it should work.  If your localhost is the Ubuntu box, you need to setup your network and use your Ubuntu's IP Address to receive the network requests.